# How to read date, time and Timestamp from hbase column

Tags: java, scala, hbase

I create following table in Hbase using Phoenix.

```
CREATE TABLE test_Table
( test_date date not null,
CONSTRAINT PK_test PRIMARY KEY (test_date)
);
```

Then insert one record into the same using following command.

```
upsert into test_Table(test_date) values('2013-11-30');
```

I am able to read string, int, float and double data type values from Hbase using. Hbase client API but not date type.

I am using following code to read all but not sure how to read date from Bytes.

```
    import org.apache.spark._
    import org.apache.spark.rdd._
    import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
    import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
    import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
    import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
    import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration
    import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark.HBaseContext
    import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Scan
    import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes
    import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
    import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.PrefixFilter
    import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.{ TableName, HBaseConfiguration }
    import java.io.File
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

def scanHBaseTable(tableName: String, sqlContext: SQLContext): Unit = {

@transient val conf = getHbaseConfiguration();
@transient var scan = new Scan()
//scan.setAllowPartialResults(Constants.ALLOW_HBASE_PARTIAL_SCAN)
//scan.setCaching(Constants.HBASE_SCAN_CACHE)  

val hbaseContext = new HBaseContext(sqlContext.sparkContext, conf);
val hbaseRawRDD = hbaseContext.hbaseRDD(TableName.valueOf(tableName), scan)
hbaseRawRDD.foreach(v =>
  {
    println(Bytes.toString(v._1.get()))
    println((new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(Bytes.toString(v._1.get()))))
  })

println("Length: " + hbaseRawRDD.map(r => r._1.copyBytes()).collect().length);
```

}

Can someone provide me solution for the same?

Answer (score 0):

The type of v is `(ImmutableBytesWritable, Result)` So you can get the date from `Result` object.
You can use method `result.getColumnLatestCell(family, qualifier).getTimestamp`.

I don't know what families or qualifiers Phoenix is using, you can list all values inside the table and know the structure they are using. You can use method `Result.getMap` which returns `Map[Family, Map[Qualifier, Map[CreateTime, Value]]]`